# Git / Github submodule specific branch

Tags: git, github

I forked a submodule project on github and modified it.

I created new local and origin branches for my modifications, and set it as default branch in github.

Now when I'm adding the submodule into a project, it is not my branch but the old head branch that is being pulled.

How can I make it that my newly created branch will be pulled by default from github ?

How can I switch submodule branches within the submodule, within my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to merge the master branch with my newly created branch...